# Confusion regarding findOwnInput function with on-chain code

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, plutustx, on-chain, validator

## Context

I was looking for a simple way to get exact `TxOut` on on-chain code to validate if funds are to be unlocked to correct wallet address. While looking in plutus haddoc I have found this function:

```
{-# INLINABLE findOwnInput #-}
-- | Find the input currently being validated.
findOwnInput :: ScriptContext -> Maybe TxInInfo
findOwnInput ScriptContext{scriptContextTxInfo=TxInfo{txInfoInputs}, scriptContextPurpose=Spending txOutRef} =
    find (\TxInInfo{txInInfoOutRef} -> txInInfoOutRef == txOutRef) txInfoInputs
findOwnInput _ = Nothing
```

This function returns:

```
-- | An input of a pending transaction.
data TxInInfo = TxInInfo
    { txInInfoOutRef   :: TxOutRef
    , txInInfoResolved :: TxOut
    } deriving stock (Generic, Haskell.Show, Haskell.Eq)
```

And here is where most of my confusion comes from - `getOwnInput` returns `TxInInfo` which has `TxOut`. All I see is `TxIn` is `TxOut`.
This makes it really unclear to me exactly which part of **locking** or **unlocking** transaction *UTXO* `getOwnInput` function returns.

Lets say that I have `10 Ada` in `wallet A` and I'm creating locking transaction `TX1` of `2 Ada` to `SC1`. The way I see it `TX1` should look like this:

1. **UTXO1** of `10 ADA` is created by taking all the funds from `wallet A`.
2. **UTXO2** of `10 ADA - 2 ADA - fees1` is created and is sent back to `wallet A`.
3. **UTXO3** of `2 ADA` is created and sent to `SC1`.

Lets say that now I'm trying to unlock `2 ADA` from `SC1` back to `wallet A` by creating `TX2`:

1. **UTXO4** `10 ADA - 2 ADA - fees1` are taken from `wallet A` to pay for `fees2`
2. **UTXO5** `2 ADA` is being taken from `SC1`
3. **UTXO6** `2 ADA` are sent to `wallet A`
4. **UTXO7** `10 ADA - 2 ADA - fees1 - fees2` are sent back to `wallet A`

---

## Main question

So my main question is. Which of these **UTXO**s does the function `getOwnInput` return as a `txInInfoResolved` when `TX2` is created?

#### Bonus question

When `TX2` is created, from Plutus validator point of view, which of **UTXO**s are `TxOut` and which are `TxIn`?

Comment: My guess would be that answer to main question is **UTXO3**, because on this tx `pubKeyOutput` returns `Nothing`. I suppose it is because **UTXO3** goes into smartcontract which doesn't have `PubKeyHash` but has `ValidatorHash` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `findOwnInput` in a validator returns the value contained in the Script-UTxO that is currently being validated. In your example above it is the one with 2 Ada in it.

Your example above is, however, not correctly formulated: UTXO4 is in fact UTXO2 and UTXO5 is UTXO3, also UTXO7 and UTXO4 are not necessary.